# How do I remove the master tag from Powershell?

Tags: git, powershell

I have tried removing the .git file but to no avail.
I have tried `rm .git` but the master tag becomes "unknown".
What should I be doing instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For remove the .git file, you can try this step :

```
cd /repo folder/
```

to go to the file directory then

```
ls -a
```

to see all files hidden and unhidden

```
.git .. .gitignore .etc
```

if you like you can check the repo origin

```
git remote -v
```

now delete .git which contains everything about git

```
 rm -rf .git
```

after deleting, you would discover that there is no git linked check    remote again

```
git remote -v
```